# Producing MoleculePlots of pigments

Tags: curated-data, chemistry

Of course no chemical database is complete, but I would like to create as large a list of `MoleculePlot`s of pigments (organic or inorganic) as is available through the `ChemicalData` database, for instance:

```
ChemicalData["PigmentOrange43", "MoleculePlot"]
```

[image: PigmentOrange43 molecule poot]

The three big problems in this effort are that

1. there is no reliable way to search the `ChemicalData` database for pigments
2. a representative list of pigments, such as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_inorganic_pigments), lists them in a form that is not directly usable to `ChemicalData`
3. once you even find an appropriate representation (often by lots of trial and error with semantic input), one finds there is no such entry in the database.

In short:  What is the most effective way to automate the search for pigments in `ChemicalData` that contain `MoleculePlot`s?

Comment: Going by the definition of "inorganic" I am accustomed to, your example is not inorganic.

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive:  Fair enough.  My example was just to show a ChemicalPlot.  I'd be happier still if we could find organic and inorganic pigments.  (I'll edit my question.)

Comment: You may also want to expand your search to the term "dyes" in addition to pigments. As a chemist, I tend to think of organic soluble "dyes" and inorganic insoluble (dispersible) "pigments". See e.g. [Wikipedia's List of dyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dyes).

Comment: It's too bad there is no immediately accessible API for the [Colour Index](https://colour-index.com/); as Jason notes, Wikipedia has a sizable, but not very extensive list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of these compounds in `ChemicalData` may be limited at the moment.

```
Select[ChemicalData[], 
 StringContainsQ[CanonicalName[#], "Pigment"] &]
```

[image]

But you can use data from Wikipedia combined with a connection to PubChem to get data about pigments.  Here I picked the organic pigments as they are more likely to be a single molecule, simpler than the inorganic solvents listed in the OP.

```
pigments = 
 WikipediaData["Category" -> "Organic pigments", "CategoryMembers"]

(* {"Paris green","Verdigris","Pigment Yellow 13",<<32>>,
      "Rose madder","Bistre","Alizarin"} *)
```

Now grab the pubchem CID number from the Wikipedia pages, and use this with [`ServiceExecute`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ServiceExecute.html) to get an SDF file for each pigment,

```
cidFromWikiPageTitle = 
  StringCases[WikipediaData[#, "SummaryWikicode"], 
    "PubChem = " ~~ cid : Longest[NumberString] :> cid] &;

pigmentCIDS = 
 Association[# -> cidFromWikiPageTitle[#] & /@ pigments] // 
   DeleteCases[{}] // Map[First]

(* <|"Paris green" -> "22833492", 
 "Pigment Yellow 13" -> "73462", "Pigment Yellow 12" -> "186342", 
 "Naphthol AS" -> "66719", "Pigment violet 23" -> "20813033", 
 "Dibromoanthanthrone" -> "78084", "Pigment yellow 185" -> "5489883", 
 "Pigment yellow 139" -> "5488898", "Perinone" -> "78141", 
 "Pigment Yellow 10" -> "21118695", "Pigment Yellow 81" -> "89597", 
 "Pigment yellow 83" -> "21733", "Pigment Yellow 16" -> "22288", 
 "Naphthol Red" -> "5359812", "Quinacridone" -> "13976", 
 "Indigo dye" -> "5318432", "Alizarin" -> "6293"|> *)
```

Now import SDF data for the pigments from PubChem,

```
pigmentSDFData =
  Normal[ServiceExecute["PubChem", 
      "CompoundSDF", {"CompoundID" -> #}]] & /@ pigmentCIDS;

Keys@First@pigmentSDFData

(* {"EdgeRules", "EdgeTypes", "FormalCharges", "Graphics3D", \
"Header", "MassNumbers", "Metadata", "StructureDiagram", \
"VertexCoordinates", "VertexTypes", "MOL"} *)
```

The `"Graphics3D"` element for many of these is actually taken from 2D coordinates, but the rest of the data is computable

```
RandomChoice[pigmentSDFData]["Metadata"] // Short

(* {{"PUBCHEM_COMPOUND_CID"->13976,<<31>>,"PUBCHEM_BONDANNOTATIONS"->{{11,13,8},<<24>>,{8,9,8}}}} *)

ImageCollage[Flatten@Values@pigmentSDFData[[All, "StructureDiagram"]],
  Background -> White]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  (+1) . Let me wait for a day or two to see if there is a more extensive and complete solution, but if not, I'll accept this.